# Python ─ UTF-8 filename from HTML form via CherryPy

Tags: python, html, encoding, utf-8, cherrypy

```
Python Header:      # ! /usr/bin/env python
                    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
                    # image_upload.py

Cherrypy Config:    cherrypy.config.update(
                        {'tools.encode.on': True,
                         'tools.encode.encoding': 'utf-8',
                         'tools.decode.on': True,
                        },)

HTML Header:        <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
                    content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"></head>

""" Python        2.7.3
    Cherrypy      3.2.2
    Ubuntu        12.04
"""
```

With an HTML form, I'm uploading an image file to a database. That works so far without problems. However, if the filename ist not 100% in ASCII, there seems to be no way to retrieve it in UTF-8. This is weird, because with the HTML text input fields it works without problems, from saving until showing. Therefore I assume that it's an encoding or decoding problem with the web application framework CherryPy, because the upload is handeld by it, [like here](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/uploading.html).

How it works:
The HTML form POSTs the uploaded file to another Python function, which receives the file in the standard dictionary `**kwargs`. From here you get the filename with extention, like this: `filename = kwargs['file'].filename`. But that's already with the wrong encoding. Until now the image hasn't been processed, stored or used in any way.

I'm asking for a solution, which would prevent it, to just parse the filename and change it back "manually". I guess the result already is in UTF-8, which makes it cumbersome to get it right. That's why getting CherryPy to do it, might be the best way. But maybe it's even an HTML issue, because the file comes from a form.

Here are the wrong decoded umlauts.
What I need is the input as result.

```
input → result        input → result  
  ä   →   Ã¤            Ä   →   Ã„  
  ö   →   Ã¶            Ö   →   Ã– 
  ü   →   Ã¼            Ü   →   Ãœ
```

Following are the failed attempts to get the right result, which would be: "Würfel"
NOTE: `img_file = kwargs['file']`

---

- original attempt:

  ```
  result = img_file.filename.rsplit('.',1)[0]
  ```

  result: "WÃ¼rfel"

---

- change system encoding:

  ```
  reload(sys)
  sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
  ```

  result: "WÃ¼rfel"

---

- encoding attempt 1:

  ```
  result = img_file.filename.rsplit('.',1)[0].encode('utf-8')
  ```

  result: "WÃ¼rfel"

---

- encoding attempt 2:

  ```
  result = unicode(img_file.filename.rsplit('.',1)[0], 'urf-8')
  ```

  Error Message:

  ```
  TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
  ```

---

- decoding attempt:

  ```
  result = img_file.filename.rsplit('.',1)[0].decode('utf-8')
  ```

  Error Message:

  ```
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)
  ```

---

- cast attempt:

  ```
  result = str(img_file.filename.rsplit('.',1)[0])
  ```

  Error Message:

  ```
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)
  ```

---

Comment: please post a `repr(img_file.filename)` so we can create the same bytearray in your context

Comment: @PaoloCasciello, `repr(img_file.filename)` returned this `u'W\xc3\xbcrfel.jpg'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying with your string it seems I can get the filename using latin1 encoding.

```
>>> s = u'W\xc3\xbcrfel.jpg'
>>> print s.encode('latin1')
Würfel.jpg
>>>
```

You simply need to use that `.encode('latin1')` before splitting.
But the problem here is broader. You really need to figure out why your web encoding is `latin1` instead of `utf8`. I don't know cherrypy but try to ensure to use utf8 or you could get in other glitches when serving your application through a webserver like apache or nginx.

Comment: Thanks so far. For now this has to do. When I've found the real solution with CherryPy, I'll post it in an edit.

Comment: @JonathanRoot the proper CherryPy way is to use `cherrypy.tools.encode`/`cherrypy.tools.decode` but `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">` seems to tell browser to use different encoding so this is where you were stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you serve your HTML with charset ISO-8859-1; this makes the browsers confused and they use the charset also when sending to server. Serve all your HTML always with UTF-8, code in UTF-8, and set your terminal to UTF-8, and you shouldn't have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added the meta tag as a solution attempt to this problem. I confused UTF/8 with ISO-8859-1, so I wouldn'd have thought of it being a problem.

Comment: You should serve with Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8, and everywhere consistently say that your charset is UTF-8; ubuntu uses UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: So when my page is going to be used from different systems, maybe I should leave this within the code: reload(sys) sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

Comment: @JonathanRoot the meta tag is ignored due to an old IE security problem with japanese encodings. that's why one should always use utf8 with the content-encoding server response header.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, I've come to believe that the reload(sys) only affects my system, not the clients' ones. So using it wouldn'd help.

Comment: @PaoloCasciello, I'll try to find out more about it. But I think for me it's CherryPy, with its WSGI server. And it should be set effectively to UTF-8, because sometimes I get a "406 Not Acceptable" error from CherryPy, when something's wrong with my code. It contains information about a "Accept-Charset header" and that the UTF-8 encoding has been tried.

Comment: As PaoloCasciello already mentioned, changing the meta tag didn't change anything.